# Encoding difference in mysql and apache spark?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have been using Apache spark to read data from a MySQL server. The data contains a lot of special characters and some other unreadable characters. I need to convert a SQL query to Spark. I converted the query to spark and the results are not matching.

Later I found about these special characters. But the interesting part is that during the first read from DB the spark dataframe has the same number of rows as in sql table. There is a column called productCode (varchar) in the table. But the number of distinct productCode in both spark and SQL are different. I don't know why this happens.

The encoding of MySQL is utf8mb4. I tried with utf8, latin1 etc. But still get the same error. What should I try? I the code is a pyspark code.

The connector is given below:

```
dburl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useServerPrepStmts=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false"
```

Comment: [mcve] would be useful.

Comment: Or can I know, is there any encoding difference between spark and MYSQL? How do I make the spark SQL use the same encoding as MYSQL?